# 2 Threads in vb.net - unable to access the same class at the same time

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

Novice Programmer here - I have an application with two threads that I start, they then run two different loops. Someplace along the lines of the loops both threads access the same class. In one loop I am instantiating an object in the constructor of that class, then using that object in a method - Then when the second loop tries to instantiate the same class it basically just sits on the constructor and doesn't execute that line of code.

Am I explaining my problem clear enough? Does anyone have any idea why this is happening, or more importantly why?

I have been looking into SyncLock but I don't how I would implement this here. Should I just SyncLock my whole class, so only one loop can access it at a time? I feel like this kind of defeats the purpose of Threading then. Any help anyone can offer is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show any sample code?

Comment: Not easily - I have 13 classes and 3 forms working together in these loops...and I can post how i Make my threads, but thats three line of codes is pretty easy. I can post the line of code where its breaking at, but the same constructor is called and working several times over before it gets the point where both threads are trying to access the class at the same time.

Comment: can you make a simple program which exposes the issue?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say two threads access a class at the same time. A class is some data plus some code; there is no restriction on two threads running the same code (a thread is pretty much an instruction pointer, registers, and a stack), and the only time threads are restricted in accessing the same data is if you use something like `SyncLock`. @didierc has it right - make the smallest program you can that has the same problem, and share that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Private Shared Variables ended up being the answer.